# argsort isnt sorting the 2d array properly?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Ive been stuck on this all day, because I really cant see where its going wrong.

```
x=[[9.62825826e-04 7.54653307e+00 1.54219786e+01 1.56003006e+01
  7.56356875e+00]
 [2.13913061e+01 7.99323940e-01 4.54427893e+01 2.40201556e+01
  1.69257932e+01]
 [4.52324126e+01 4.54569526e+01 9.69601669e-03 4.59271880e+01
  2.85163398e+01]
 [4.54089845e+01 2.32183545e+01 4.59253670e+01 2.47722494e-03
  2.36843962e+01]
 [2.14375302e+01 1.69550555e+01 2.85025533e+01 2.44858206e+01
  7.98947124e-01]] 

i=x.argsort(axis=None) #axis=None to flatten whole array and sort over all values
j=np.reshape(i, (x.shape)) #reshape the sorted indices in a meaningful way

for k in tree1.keys(): #just enumerating over some dictionaries that form part of my code, not necessary to know what they are
    for p in tree2.keys(): #basically just counting the length of the array in x and y directions
        if j[k][p]==0: #to find lowest value value indices, so i can access the value later
            print("heres the index of that value", k,p)
            
print(j)
```

the result:

```
heres the index of that value 0 0
[[ 0 18 12 24  6]
 [ 1  4  2  3  9]
 [21  5 20 16 19]
 [ 8 23 22 14 10]
 [15  7 11 17 13]]
```

which isnt wrong. but then look at it for the second lowest, i.e `j[k][p]==1` in the for loop - it gives the indices indicating a value of `2.13913061e+01`, which is clearly wrong..it should give `(3,3)`, with a value of `2.47722494e-03` . I really cant see whats wrong, since i thought the flatteneing of the array was the main thing that could trip it up _ but sine it is flat, i dont need to worry about the axes, and im really confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about the result of `argsort` the wrong way around. The result of `argsort` is the list of indices, sorted by the values in the array. Therefore, the *position* of the index `1` in the result of `argsort` indicates the position of the second value in the list in the sorted array, *not* the position of the second-lowest value in the original array.

The result of `argsort` on your flattened array is as follows:

```
>>> x.argsort(axis=None)
array([ 0, 18, 12, 24,  6,  1,  4,  2,  3,  9, 21,  5, 20, 16, 19,  8, 23,
       22, 14, 10, 15,  7, 11, 17, 13], dtype=int64)
```

Therefore, the second-lowest value is on index `18` in the original array, which indeed matches the index `(3, 3)`:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(18, x.shape)
(3, 3)
```

In the result of `argsort`, the index `1` occurs at the 6th position in the array, meaning that the value `x[1]` is the sixth-lowest value in the array.

Therefore, to find the second-lowest value, you shouldn't look for the value `1` in the result of `argsort`, but you should just take the second index in the result.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much! some how not so intuitive, but makes sense. thanks again!